# GORM criteria group by in subquery

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, criteria

Let's assume the following Grails domains:

```
Owner {
 String name
 static hasMany [cars: Cars]
}

Car {
 Date inspectionDate
}
```

I want to be able to **search for `Owner`s** through Criteria, with the following rule: **Most recent `Car` by `inspectionDate` in `Owner`'s cars list being lower than `*given date*`**.

As an example, I want to apply the following code to a select query in GORM:

```
queryResultsList = allOwnersList.filter { owner -> 
    owner.cars.min{ car -> car.inspectionDate }.inspectionDate < myDate
}
```

I need to achieve it using Criteria because I am already filtering `Owner`s on other fields.
The whole given code is used as an example, some parts of the original code has been ommited, and source code is not about cars and owners.

As on first thought I assumed I needed a subquery in `SQL` to retrieve my data as I expected, I tried the following:

```
Owner.createCriteria().list {
    // [...] some filters on other fields 
    cars {
        lt('inspectionDate', params.inspectionDate)

        'in'('inspectionDate', new grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria(Owner).list {
            projections {
                cars {
                    min('inspectionDate')
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I also tried to add `groupProperty` in different places in the projection, ending with `MissingPropertyException`.

I am using Grails 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

After a few days testing solutions, I've come to the following one:

```
Owner.createCriteria().list {
    // [...] some filters on other fields 
    cars {
        lt('inspectionDate', params.inspectionDate)

        'in'('inspectionDate', Owner.createCriteria().list {

            projections {
                cars {
                    min('inspectionDate')
                }
                groupProperty 'id'
            }
        // this allows to only get first property, which is inspectionDate
        }.collect { it[0] })
    }
}
```

However, I still feel like doing things wrong. In particular, the `collect` part looks like a code smell.

I am posting this because it *does what I need*, but any help with finding a *good* solution will be appreciated.